# Where to view the list of "Sandbox" Payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When using the PayPal Checkout Button (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/), where can we find the list of test payments (using Test Credit Cards) that have been transacted?

I've been trying to search through the Dashboard but it it not there in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Are you logged with your sandbox account eg: myaccount-facilitator@gmail.com?
I'm seeming my transactions at:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/mep/dashboard